Setting up a vault agent sidecar in an ECS service via terraform to pass env variables stored in the vault
As the title suggests, I am trying to setup vault agent sidecars on services deploying on AWS ECS.  I want to store the services env variables in the vault as well as use vault to generate certificates.  I am also using terraform to deploy this.
My vault is dedicated through Hashicorp platform.
I am unable to figure out how to write the setup for the task definition as well as the config file for the vault agent.
Here is what I currently have, though I have not tried to implement the pki engine for certificates yet.
The ecs service resource:
resource "aws_ecs_task_definition" "task" {
  family                   = var.service_name
  network_mode             = "awsvpc"
  requires_compatibilities = ["FARGATE"]
  cpu                      = var.cpu
  memory                   = var.memory
  task_role_arn            = var.ecs_task_role_arn
  execution_role_arn       = var.ecs_task_execution_role_arn

  container_definitions = <<DEFINITION
[
{
    "image": "${var.container_image}",
    "name": "${var.service_name}",
    "readonlyRootFilesystem": false,
    "networkMode": "awsvpc",
    "environmentFiles": [
        {
            "value": "/etc/secrets/env_vars", 
            "type" : "s3" 
        }
    ],
    "portMappings": [
        {
            "name": "http",
            "containerPort": ${var.port1},
            "hostPort": ${var.port1},
            "protocol": "tcp",
            "appProtocol": "http"
        }
    ],
    "logConfiguration": {
        "logDriver": "awslogs",
        "options": {
            "awslogs-group": "${var.service_name}",
            "awslogs-region": "${var.region}",
            "awslogs-stream-prefix": "${var.environment}",
            "awslogs-create-group": "true"
        }
    },
    "mountPoints": [
        {
            "sourceVolume": "vault-secrets",
            "containerPath": "/etc/secrets"  
        }
    ]
},
{
    "name" : "${var.service_name}-datadog-agent",
    "image" : "public.ecr.aws/datadog/agent:latest",
    "cpu" : 100,
    "memory" : 512,
    "essential" : true,
    "portMappings" : [
        {
          "hostPort" : 8126,
          "protocol" : "tcp",
          "containerPort" : 8126
        }
    ],
    "environment" : [
        {
          "name" : "ECS_FARGATE",
          "value" : "true"
        }
}

    ]
},
{
    "name" : "vault-agent",
    "image" : "hashicorp/vault-agent:latest",
    "cpu" : 50,
    "memory" : 128,
    "essential" : false,
    "command" : ["vault", "agent", "-config=/vault/config/${var.service_name}-vault-agent-config.hcl"],
    "mountPoints" : [
        {
            "sourceVolume": "vault-secrets",
            "containerPath": "/vault/secrets"
        },
        {
            "sourceVolume": "vault-config",
            "containerPath": "/vault/config"  
        }
    ],
    "environment" : [
        {
            "name": "VAULT_ADDR",
            "value": "${var.vault_address}"
        }
    ]
}
]
DEFINITION

  volume {
  name = "vault-secrets"
  docker_volume_configuration {
    scope = "shared"
  }
}

volume {
  name = "vault-config"
  docker_volume_configuration {
    scope = "shared"
  }
}

}

And this is my vault agent config template:
pid_file = "/tmp/vault-agent-pid"

auto_auth {
  method "aws" {
    mount_path = "auth/aws"
    config = {
      type = "iam"
      role = "${iam_role}"  
    }
  }

  sink "file" {
    config = {
      path = "/vault/secrets/env_vars"  
    }
  }
}

vault {
  address = "${vault_address}"  
}

template {
  source      = "/vault/templates/env.ctmpl"
  destination = "/vault/secrets/env_vars"  
}

The error I get when trying to deploy via terraform is:
Error: creating ECS Task Definition (test): operation error ECS: RegisterTaskDefinition, https response error StatusCode: 400, RequestID: f612cedb-f65a-4a9c-adb3-998a1fbc5f54, ClientException: Invalid arn syntax.
with module.ecs_service.aws_ecs_task_definition.task
on ecs/main.tf line 2, in resource "aws_ecs_task_definition" "task":
resource "aws_ecs_task_definition" "task" {


The "Invalid ARN syntax" points to a problem with the ARNs for task_role_arn or execution_role_arn.
Make sure that these ARNs follow the correct format (arn:aws:iam::<account-id>:role/<role-name>) and that the variables var.ecs_task_role_arn and var.ecs_task_execution_role_arn are properly defined and passed in.
You should also get more insights from running terraform plan. Use that to check if the ARNs are interpolated correctly, or enable debugging with TF_LOG=DEBUG terraform apply for a more detailed output.
